# iPhone : Simple Radio App

Tags: iphone, xcode, safari, audio-streaming, internet-radio

i am made a simple radio app which call out safari to stream audio/radio. My problem is that i don't konw how to get back control and show other content while safari is playing music. Of course i do not want the user to have to get out of the app and re-enter. I am thinking a tabbed app but i need your help to regain control.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.piratefm.gr/128.m3u"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: hm, what about media- or audio-player? [see AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Comment: I can not understand how am i going to implement those players for e-radio use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an AVAudioPlayer and init it with the URL